# Change turtle's pencolor based on recursion depth

Tags: python, recursion, colors, turtle-graphics

Anyone know how to change the turtle's pencolor based on depth of this code's recursion? I can't figure it out.

```
def drawzig2(depth,size):
 if depth == 0:
    pass
 else:
    left(90)
    fd(size/2)
    right(90)
    fd(size)
    left(45)        
    drawzig2(depth-1,size/2)       
    right(45)
    fd(-size)
    left(90)
    fd(-size)
    right(90)
    fd(-size)
    left(45)        
    drawzig2(depth-1,size/2)        
    right(45)
    fd(size)
    left(90)
    fd(size/2)
    right(90)

drawzig2(3,100)
```

Comment: Perhaps you should tell what you are trying to do and what library you are using. Your current question is _very_ unclear

Comment: Since `depth` is an argument passed the function, pick a color based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified version of your code which alters the color based on depth:

```
import turtle
import logging

colors = ['green', 'yellow', 'blue']

def drawzig2(depth, size):
    if depth == 0:
        pass
    else:
        turtle.pen(pencolor=colors[depth % len(colors)])
        logging.error(
            "Depth: " + str(depth) + " " +
            "Color: " + colors[depth % len(colors)])
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.fd(size / 2)
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.fd(size)
        turtle.left(45)
        drawzig2((depth - 1),(size / 2))
        turtle.right(45)
        turtle.fd(-size)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.fd(-size)
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.fd(-size)
        turtle.left(45)
        drawzig2((depth - 1), (size / 2))
        turtle.right(45)
        turtle.fd(size)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.fd(size / 2)
        turtle.right(90)

drawzig2(3,100)
```

Screenshot of what it starts to produce:

[image]

**EDIT:** Based on the great feedback from martineu in the comments, I revised the solution to be a bit easier to understand for the OP and included logging, which should output as below when run:

```
Depth: 3 Color: green
Depth: 2 Color: blue
Depth: 1 Color: yellow
Depth: 1 Color: yellow
Depth: 2 Color: blue
Depth: 1 Color: yellow
Depth: 1 Color: yellow
```

Comment: When I try that I get the list index out of range error. I copied it exactly.

Comment: try [logging](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) both the length of the array and the depth value when you are calling it to debug which one is not as you expect it. In the example above, there 5  colors in the array, so acceptable values would be `0,1,2,3` or `4`

Comment: Leon: `colors[0]` (e.g. `blue`) will never be used. @user2723477: With this code the maximum value that the depth argument can be when initially calling `drawzig2()` is `4`.

Comment: good point @martineau, I've adjusted the code to be more colorful with the OP's code and drop the extra element from array

Comment: It wasn't that there were too many items in the `colors` list, just that `pencolor=colors[depth]` will never get executed if `depth == 0` -- so even with your changes `colors[0]` will never be selected. I suggest you use something like `pencolor=colors[depth % len(colors}]` which would also avoid index out of range errors.

Comment: @martineau, thanks for clarifying, I really like your solution. I limited the array for now and as you stated, it won't fail if the method is passed a higher int, then the OP can add as many colors as may be required to expiriment.